# React Native how to open document picker from specific path

Tags: android, ios, react-native, filepicker, react-native-image-picker

i am create one Image Editor application and for that i have some requirements that user can Edit that image that present in App Internal path `(data/data/com.myapp/files)`

for that i have done open gallery and import (copy) in inside `data/data/com.myapp/files/Master` folder and thats work fine i am using `RNFS` for copy that images

for edit i have requirement that user can select only and only from that `data/data/com.myapp/files/Master` path

how to open `Document Picker` or `File Picker` from `data/data/com.myapp/files/Master` specific folder ?